# HTTP Server push for angular modules

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

All the recent and imminent updates to Angular to increase performance and reduce payload have convinced me it's finally time to update our website from a traditional aspnet mvc application.

I'm splitting the site into modules, including separate modules for our primary landing pages - that are reached from google or facebook ads. I obviously want to make sure these load as fast as possible.

I've used HTTP server push in the past to push down resources needed for a page before my JavaScript has kicked in and id like to do the same here.

Eg. If the aspnet server gets a request for /producttour then I want to push the 'product tour' module javascript with an http header so the server can immediately start sending it. This removes one server round trip for this file (which may be quite a large file). I also probably want to push files I know are required everywhere such as vendor.js

Yes I realize this will only apply for the first page - after which you are in an angular spa and modules will load normally.

I can't seem to find anyone else talking about this which surprises me.

- With URL hashing the filename changes every time I build so I dont know how to retrieve it in advance to send that filename hardcoded.
- Without URL hashing I may accidentally load stale code.

My best idea is to Ng build to index.htm with hashing disabled, copy that page and then manually add a ?version to it on the server side and add headers.

Comment: long shot.. are you looking into server-side rendering for faster page serve ? [angular universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

Comment: Probably not. But I suppose I should test both. Worried that that will create other issues (not sure what though)

Comment: Angular 6 routing supports lazy loading. Which means unless you go to `/producttour`, it'll never be loaded. Isn't this enough for most cases?

Comment: @Ozgur It should be mostly, but I want to avoid any flickering at all. Will have to test it I suppose. I still have a long way to go before I can justify spending too much time on implementing this, but wondered if someone else had tacked it before. I did see some definite speed increases with server push in the current site.

Comment: Let me get this straight; so when user clicks this ad of yours, the index.html, then the main bundle + whatever vendors you have and after that this separate lazy loaded module representing the landing page are being/supposed to be downloaded and your goal is to start loading all those JS assets once the index.html is about to be sent to the client, am I getting warm here?

Comment: Yes. The idea is not to mess with anything angular is doing with modules and file structure - but to add the benefit of http2 server push to my app when I know a certain module is going to be loaded.

Comment: And if it's negligible it's negligible :)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver mention me in the comments, I didn't notice you replied :).
If you knew part of the name of that particular module - that is you could identify that file, would it be possible for you to look up that file on your server and send a Link header containing that filename?

Comment: @DanMacák I'm thinking that it might be best to add a query string parameter (for cache busting) manually to the generated index.htm file from angular - this file basically never changes except when the hashed filename changes. Then I'd do exactly that on the server - `if (page == "dogs") { SetHeader(SERVER_PUSH_HEADER, 'dogs.jpg'); }`. But for CDN caching I don't want this page to be dynamic content, so I'd have to figure out a way to send that page and headers when `/dogs` was requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question basically is not exactly Angular specific, but its concern is rather what happens before the Angular actually kicks in.
The problem can be devided into two parts:

1. **How to identify** which **file** is needed (which lazy loaded module) in order to send it in the Link header?
2. Once the file is identified, how to get it and **wire it up with the rest of the application**?

---

Let's get straight to Nr.**1.**

- Your lazy loaded modules don't have to have those "ugly" hashy names necessarily, you can use `--named-chunks` and even `--output-hashing=none` together with your `ng build` command. This will generate fairly normal names you can use as ID and I am pretty sure there is some naming customization in angular-cli possible as a cherry on top, but I will leave it up to you.
- Now let's suppose you have that file directly on your **app server** and you will be able to find it even if it has a cache busting hash. For this purpose there will be a little script needed which finds it, gets the name and uses that name for sending the Link header.

  Or that file is on the **CDN** where you most probably don't want to have the cache busting hash in the filename, in which case it is again easy to identify it. The only problem is the caching, but you can solve it for example with query string modes as shown in this [Azure caching article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-query-string).

Nr.**2.** Now you have got the filename and you can send the Link header. The only other thing you have to do before you send the *index.html* is **you have to include** `<script>` tag there with `src=/path/to/the-lazy-module` for which you use information from point 1, so again a little bit of scripting or templating is needed there on the server.

I tested this approach with "sequential", then `async` and `defer` *script* tag and also made sure the lazy loaded module arrives first or last and it didn't seem to make any difference. Actually, the lazy loading is initiated from *@angular/router* (of course) and at the end performed by Webpack's `require.ensure`, which adds its own `<script>` to the `<head>` in order to get the lazy module, so my guess is it check whether such *script* is already there or not. Therefore you don't have to be afraid about the order or that it will be loaded twice, but still rather test it yourself.

The result of doing all this is your resources should be pushed at once once the *index.html* is about to be sent and the lazy loaded modules will be wired up with your application automatically once the Angular kicks in and starts looking for them.

Comment: Thanks @dan and for doing the testing. Interesting point about manually adding the script tag. I wonder how the performance is impacted if you do or don't implement this. If the server is already pushing it then I would think it would be instantly available as soon as Angular 'asks for it' when loading the module.

Comment: I tried to push public assets such that weren't declared in index.html and I didn't manage to push them. I only managed to push those declared there as `<script>`. Or is it possible to do it also without it? I don't know any other way.
Regarding performance this isn't so much of an issue, basically it is just about modifying a string being sent to the client. To make it even faster, one might use the CDN approach where the filename is always the same or somehow configure/write a webpack plugin which takes certain lazy loaded module names and pastes them into HTML document as `<script>`s.